# Double-slit experiment with erasing all the collected data

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

The question concerns the double-slit experiment with collecting the data to register through which of the slits every single photon has passed. As I understand, in this case, when the photons are being registered, they should produce a pattern of two spots on the receiving screen, right?

Did anyone try erasing all the collected data before revealing/examining the resulting pattern? Would it turn out that in this case an interfered pattern is being produced? Yes, we've collected the data, so the light should behave like a bunch of particles, but all the data have been erased before we knew what pattern is produced, so the light *could* behave like a wave.

Thanks for any information on this topic.

Comment: Photons creating two spots? They create an interference pattern, decreasing light lines. You can erase the pattern at any point and start over, the same interference pattern will grow.